# How to arm or set quadcopter (Iris+) mode while running ArduCopter SITL with ROS/Gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, px4, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am referring to http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/using-rosgazebo-simulator-with-sitl/

Based on the code, the following is my understanding of what's happening -

- You receive input to ROS (mavros) via UDP socket as motor_speeds. These inputs are received from the SITL and ArduCopter code.
- You publish these motor speeds to the corresponding topic for Gazebo simulation.
- Data from the simulated vehicle is then send back to SITL code, over the UDP socket.

However, I still don't know how I can use Mavros alongside with SITL to be able to send commands to arm, disarm, takeoff, or change the mode over the socket. Any guidance regarding this would be appreciated!

(Please let me know if any clarification is required)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221299/how-to-arm-or-set-quadcopter-(iris+)-mode-while-running-arducopter-sitl-with-ros/gazebo?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2015-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a pull request for a plugin that talks to SITL using [SIM_Gazebo](https://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot/blob/master/libraries/SITL/SIM_Gazebo.cpp):

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/2010/aerodynamics-plugin-and-arducopter-sitl/diff

A short instruction is [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/8a13be3233deeb2b0f1ef12f80691302c9be6e62/worlds/iris_standoff_demo.world?fileviewer=file-view-default#iris_standoff_demo.world-5), [here's what it looks like](https://youtu.be/n_M5Vs5FBGY)
and we'll add a tutorial down the road.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0